# Upgrade from ruby 1.8.6 to 1.8.7 in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ruby

Our server has ruby 1.8.7 and i have 1.8.6 locally.  I want to upgrade my local machine (which has ubuntu 9.10) to ruby 1.8.7 - NOT to 1.9 or any later versions.  I tried `sudo apt-get install ruby1.8.7` but there's no package for that.

Comment: This looks more like a question for ServerFault than StackOverflow. I looked over there and there is a similar question there for Ubuntu Hardy - http://serverfault.com/questions/84679/upgrading-ubuntu-hardy-to-ruby-1-8-7

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, i'm looking at that other page now, but without any luck so far :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried RVM? There is also a system-wide installation available for servers.

http://rvm.io/

http://rvm.io/deployment/system-wide/

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using RVM.

RVM is a system wide or user wide service (depending on your preference) that allows you to install multiple versions of Ruby without causing problems.  Installation is very easy to get started with and since it allows for different versions of Ruby to be installed, you could easily continue programming in 1.8.6 for one project and seamlessly switch to 1.8.7 to program for the server you are working with.  You can even set different users to have different versions of Ruby set as their default if you go the user-wide way.

Make sure you have git and curl installed.

https://rvm.io

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

It does take a little getting used to but it is a very powerful tool for developing with different versions of Ruby and even different versions of the Rails Gem.  This is great too,  you can have multiple Gemsets as well.  So, for instance, if you need to test a new Gem or version of a Gem without mucking up a stable one you already have installed, you can create a separate Gemset and play around with it and switch back at your convenience.

Has saved me from having a lot of headaches in the past.